# Adding two big numbers in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, addition, biginteger

I need help with adding two big numbers (by big I mean that don't fit into `eax` for example). I know I have to use `adc` but it doesn't give me good results.

```
SYSCALL = 0X80
STDIN = 0
STDOUT = 1
SYSREAD = 3
SYSWRITE = 4
SYSEXIT = 1

.section .data

a1: .long 4000000000
a2: .long 4000000000
equals: .long 0

.section .text
.globl _start

_start:

xor %edx, %edx

movl a1, %eax
movl a2, %ebx
adc a2, %eax
movl %eax, equals

mov $SYSEXIT, %eax
int $SYSCALL
```

I check the result with print equals under gdb.

Comment: If they don't fit in EAX, they won't fit in a 32-bit `.long`. In what format are you trying to get the output?

Comment: a1 and a2 fit in extented register, the output don't. I know that adding two numbers in word size should be made somehow. I just don't know how.

Comment: Write an assembly marco (using from struct) for big numbers and save digits in array :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the most stylish assembler, but something like this should work;

```
a1: .long 4000000000
a2: .long 4000000000
result_lo: .long 0
result_hi: .long 0

movl a1, %eax                ; load a1 into %eax
addl a2, %eax                ; add a2 to %eax
movl %eax, result_lo         ; store low 32 bits of result

movl $0, %eax                ; clear %eax
adcl $0, %eax                ; add carry + 0 to %eax
movl %eax, result_hi         ; store high 32 bits of result
```

`ADC` adds the two operands + the carry from the last operation. No need to use it for the low 32 bits, but for the second 32 bits, you'll want the overflow from the last add to carry over.

Comment: Hmm.. reult_lo is -589934592 and result_hi is 1. I notoced that a1 when print is -294967296 instead of 4mln. Mhm.. this makes no sense. It should fit into eax/long/32b. and it gives no error when linking.

Comment: Ok i got it now, it's signed long... damn, thats a problem then.

Comment: Okey, but how did you get that -589934592 is DCD65000? Can you give me a source to it?

Comment: I'll mark it as answeared, but please tell me how to convert that thing :)

Comment: Just read the value as an unsigned long and you'll get 3705032704 (or, in hex, DCD65000)